# Calculating height of binary tree as a void function

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm learning C++ and trying to write a void function that will calculate the height of a Node. The function has to be of void type so it cannot return anything but should calculate the height of the node correctly. Below is my code:

```
void computeHeight(Node *n) {

  if (!n->left && !n->right){
    n->height = 0;
  }
  else if (n->left && !n->right){
    n->height = 1 + computeHeight(n->left);
  }
  else if (!n->left && n->right){
    n->height = 1 + computeHeight(n->right);
  }
  else {
    if (computeHeight(n->left) > computeHeight(n->right)){
      n->height = 1 + computeHeight(n->left);
    }
    else {
      n->height = 1 + computeHeight(n->right);
    }
  }
}
```

I think I'm getting errors because it doesn't like operators such as '+' in void function. Please advise!

Comment: `1 + computeHeight(n->left);` - You are making a recursive call to a function of type void.Hence, the error.

Comment: Change return type to a type of `n->height` member and add `return n->height;` at the end of the function

Comment: How can I write it as a void function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not allowed to change function return type (even though it enforces a rather strange implementation)

---

You cannot add `1` to result of `computeHeight`, because the latter returns nothing at all.

However, `computeHeight` does something. It has so called *side effect*. This effect is "after completion of `computeHeight(n)`, `n->height` will be set to value of height (from leaves) of given node". You can use that:

```
else if (n->left && !n->right){
    computeHeight(n->left);
    n->height = 1 + n->left->height;
}
```

In the last case, you need to first `computeHeight` of both subtrees and then compare the side effects:

```
else {
  computeHeight(n->left);
  computeHeight(n->right);
  n->height = 1 + std::max(n->left->height, n->right->height); //slightly refactored ;)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be both fixed and simplified as follows (untested):

```
void computeHeight(Node *n) {
  if (!n)
    return;

  computeHeight(n->left);
  computeHeight(n->right);

  auto left_height = n->left ? n->left->height : 0;
  auto right_height = n->right ? n->right->height : 0;

  n->height = std::max(left_height, right_height) + 1;
}
```